# Godot: Node as child of Node2D stays visible when parent turns invisible

Tags: visible, godot, invisible

turning a Node2D invisible does not apply to it's base-class-Node children – these stay visible. Changing their type to Node2D then makes them become invisible along with the parent.

I see that a base-Node cannot be turned invisibe, but having some buried deep within my scene-tree, I wonder if it wouldn't be practical to have them adopt the behaviour of their parent in such a case.

Is there a reason for this behaviour? And can I somehow make a Node get invisible in such a case as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Inheritance chain for a `Node2D` looks like this:

```
Node2D < CanvasItem < Node < Object
```

The `visibility` property is on the `CanvasItem`. So, the `Node2D` has that property because it inherits from `CanvasItem`. A `Node` does not have a `visibility` property, and therefore, it's not possible to set such a property there.

Additionally, a `Node` item by itself is not visible in-game. That is, there's nothing rendered for it by default.

---

```
Sprite1
    Node2D
        Sprite2
```

If you turn off visibility of `Sprite1`, then `Sprite2` is also made invisible.

However, with this structure:

```
Sprite1
    Node
        Sprite2
```

Turning off the visibility of `Sprite1` does not impact the visibility of `Sprite2`.

(Thanks to Jgodfrey on godotengine.org!)